# Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar due to Git

Tags: homebrew

Rather fond of git and don't want to lose it. Is it safe to run `brew link` as suggested here:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it is safe to do that.

Note also that OS X comes with `git` in `/usr/bin`, so you don't really need the brewed Git.

The warning message is mainly targeted at packages that provide libraries that other packages link against.  That is not the case for `git`.